# What does UEKR mean in Oracle Linux?

Tags: oracle-linux

All files in Oracle Linux have a UEK suffix, e.g `kernel-uek-debug-devel-4.1.12-124.35.2.el7uek.x86_64.rpm`

What does it mean?

Comment: AFAIK, it's "Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel" (UEK). There's more info [here](https://github.com/oracle/linux-uek).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UEK means Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel. This kernel has RedHat code base line, but Oracle enhanced the kernel with features like Ksplice. It supposed to be well tested in Engineered Systems and Cloud Environments.
I would say that UEK kernels are not intended for home users.

More information in:

[Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel](https://docs.oracle.com/en/operating-systems/uek/)